# Does v3 of Google reCAPTCHA ever prompt suspicious with reCAPTCHA challenge?

Tags: google-contacts-api, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I am considering implementing reCAPTCHA v3 for the website of my small business. I understand that v3 detects suspicious users and reports them to website owners. My question is whether or not the website owner or Google ever throws a reCAPTCHA challenge at the suspicious user at any point in v3? If this is not done, how is the suspicious user or bot dealt with?

Thanks,
Winston Birch, Esq

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "no". The v3 never interrupts user flow. Instead, each type of request you configure would return "score" from 0 to 1.

You will decide how to deal with that score on your own. For example, you can block the request for low score or add additional validation.

You have to decide what is "low" score for your site by yourself. 0 score indicates that it's more likely a bot. 1 - more likely a human. But there is no guarantee bots would get high score and vise versa. By default Google recommend to consider legitimate requests with score 0.5 and higher. You can always tune this for your site later.

Also please note, after you push the code into production, Google algorithms would need some time to accommodate to your traffic. So it's high likely for a small period of time your scores could be not accurate.

Cheers!